# how to add Java EE perspective in Eclipse Photon?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I could not find the Java EE perspective in Eclipse Photon. I want to develop a web application, but for this I need to change the Eclipse perspective. But, I could not find the Java EE perspective.  Can anybody tell me how to add this to Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

`window -> open perspective -> select Java EE view`

If you do not have It is because you have not downloaded It:
[image]
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/photon/r/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers

Comment: Photon is outdated, the current version is 2018-09: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-09/r/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers